# How To use Patch Method Path Parameter in VB.net

Tags: .net, api, httpwebrequest, path-parameter

I have a httpwebrequest Patch Method that works if I run it in Postman.
because there is a path param in it.

```
https://testapi.kyoo.com/api/v3/businessportal/queues/:branchId/:queueGroupId/:queueId/:state
```

in which have a paramaters:

```
:branchId :80971198-4983-45a5-a4f4-bbf486dd88d1
:queueGroupId : 8b19f885-1903-43d9-9b2f-b226ac8749e4
:queueId : f3906c41-9d95-4746-aa13-d2e39eb59c99
:state : done
```

my problem is that if I use this httpwebrequest(below)

```
https://testapi.kyoo.com/api/v3/business-portal/queues?:branchId =80971198-4983-45a5-a4f4-bbf486dd88d1&:queueGroupId=8b19f885-1903-43d9-9b2f-b226ac8749e4&:queueId=f3906c41-9d95-4746-aa13-d2e39eb59c99&:state=done
```

it give me "Internal Server error 500"

what did I miss?

by the way I want to code that in .net and I don't have any  Idea how to pass parameters.

Comment: Update

https://testapi.kyoo.com/api/v3/business-portal/queues/:branchId/{80971198-4983-45a5-a4f4-bbf486dd88d1}/:queueGroupId/{8b19f885-1903-43d9-9b2f-b226ac8749e4}/:queueId/{0529a498-3a14-43c6-87a3-1469ce270e97}/:state/{Done}

heres the other code but it seems that {"statusCode":18016,"error":"INVALID_QUEUE_STATUS","source":"status must be either serve, done or remove only."}

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

For me to be use PATCH METHOD

I need to over ride    `requests1.Method = "PATCH"` it's method and add this

lines     `request.Headers.Add("X-Http-Method-Override", "PATCH")`

by the way my vb.net behind codes is

```
Dim requests1 As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(webr & branchkey & "/" & GroupID & "/" & setqueueid & "/done")
            requests1.Method = "PATCH"
            requests1.Headers.Add("X-Http-Method-Override", "PATCH")
            requests1.Headers.Add("MyAuthenticator", "Mytoken")
            requests1.Proxy = Nothing
            requests1.GetResponse()
```